# Valid regex expressions won't work with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I'd like to check if user input is correct for phone numbers in two formats:

- 01 1234567 (two numbers, a space, seven numbers)
- +12 123 123 123 123 (plus sign, two numbers, a space, three numbers, a space, three numbers, a space, three numbers
- no character at all (no input)

I wrote a regex for this [[0-9]{2} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7}|](https://regex101.com/r/i4MymF/1). It works when checked with online regex checkers, but it won't work (user can write whatever they want) when used with AngularJS: `ng-pattern="[0-9]{2} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7}|"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a regex that will match the whole string that matches your patterns as optional patterns:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?:\+[0-9]{2} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7})?$/"
            ^^                                                           ^^
```

Or, a bit shorter:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?:\+[0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{3}){3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7})?$/"
```

If you define the pattern in a JS file as a variable use

```
var mypattern = /^(?:\+[0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{3}){3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7})?$/;
```

Note that when using regex delimiters the anchors are required for the regex to match entire input.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ec5AXo/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\+` - a `+` char
  - `[0-9]{2} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}` (equal to `[0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{3}){3}`) - 2 digits and then 3 occurrences of a space, 3 digits
- `|` - or

  - `[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7}` - 2 digits, space, 7 digits
- `)?` - end of the optional group
- `$` - end  of string.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My browser shows the following error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?:+[0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{3}){3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7})?$/: Nothing to repeat`.

Comment: @menteith You did not escape the `+`. Are you using it inside `ng-pattern` attribute? If not, use `[+]`.

Comment: I my source file (`jade`) I have `ng-pattern="/^(?:[+][0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{3}){3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7})?$/"` in my output html file I have `ng-pattern="/^(?:[+][0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{3}){3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7})?$/"`. There is no error yet user can input anything they want.

Comment: @menteith If you define the regex inside a JS file, use `var mypattern = /^(?:\+[0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{3}){3}|[0-9]{2} [0-9]{7})?$/;`

Comment: @menteith Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting the answer if it turned out helpful.